# How to enter the "end time" of task in cell next to start time when a cell in a subsequent row is filled with ID of the person completing the task?

Tags: excel, vba

I am setting up a spreadsheet to track information about tasks completed by employees. The way i want this to work is that an employee will have their ID scanned into the spreadsheet at the start of each task.

I have set up a sheet that allows the scanning/entry of the employee ID into column D and auto-populates an adjacent cell (column E) with the current date/time.

The bit i am struggling with is entering the "end time" of the task; when the same employee returns for a subsequent and has their badge scanned into the sheet i want the finish time of the previous task to be entered into column F of the row associated with that task.

I.e. scanning the badge into a later row in the sheet triggers the "end" of the previous task that employee was carrying out, so the start time of the second/next task is the finish time of the first/previous task.

My knowledge of VBA is very limited, and i can't think of a simple way to achieve this.

The table looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBfk8.jpg

I found some code online that I've tried to edit. The basis i'm trying to work on is for the code to:
- Search for values of a given employee ED in column D
- when a matching ID is found, copy column E from the "found row" into column F of the original row.
- it should then work through the whole of column D, stopping at each instance of the matching ID, copying and pasting as above, then moving on through the column.

Code below:

```
'Sub FindCopy()

Dim calc As Long
Dim Cel As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rFound As Range
Dim LookRange As Range
Dim CelValue As Variant

    ' Speed
    calc = Application.Calculation
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'Get Last row of data Sheet2, Col D (Stager ID)
       LastRow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Set range to look in (Stager ID)
   Set LookRange = Sheet2.Range("D2:D" & LastRow)


    ' Loop on each value (cell)
    For Each Cel In LookRange
        ' Get value to find
        CelValue = Cel.Value
        ' Look on sheet2
        With Sheet2

            ' Allow not found error
            On Error Resume Next

            Set rFound = .Cells.Find(What:=CelValue, _
                After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

            ' Reset
            On Error GoTo endo

            ' Not found, go next
            If rFound Is Nothing Then
                GoTo nextCel
            Else
                ' Found. Copy Sheet2, Col E to Sheet2 found Row, Col F

           Sheet2.Cells(Cel.Row, 6).Value = Sheet2.Cells(rFound.Row, 5).Value


            End If          

        End With
nextCel:
    Next Cel

'Reset

endo:

    With Application
        .Calculation = calc
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, currently it just pastes the first value of column E into column F for all rows associated with that employee ID.

I want it to determine the finish time for each task independently, such that i can calculate the duration of each task.

Does anyone know how to correct the code i'm using, or another (possibly much easier way) to achieve the above? Is it possible to set this up to populate "live" i.e. as employee IDs are entered?

Comment: So for every time a employee scans his badge, the first time is Starting time and the next time is Ending time. When both are filled a new task is created?

Comment: Everytime the badge is scanned, end the 1st task (add the end time on the previous row in which the badge was scanned) and add the start time for the new row in which the badge has been scanned.

So if 1st badge scan was for a task in Row 3, and the next task is started by that employee in Row 6, it would put the start time for the task started in Row 6 into both Row 6 column E and Row 3 column F (Row 3 column F is the end time for the task in Row 3). 

Does that make sense?

Comment: I.e. scanning the badge into a later row in the sheet triggers the "end" of the previous task that employee was carrying out, so the start time of the second/later task is the finish time of the first/earlier task.

Comment: But scanning the badge will always trigger starting/ending tasks, right? What I don't get is how are you feeding the scanned ID? There is nothing on your code which takes the ID from anywhere.

Comment: We manually scan a badge barcode, which essentially just represents a number, into Column D. Scanning into a row i can get the "start time" using =now and an if... but getting the end time is more difficult, and I can't work it out. Hence this post.

Comment: But that's... You should pull up a little form to scan there the badge and then taking from it the badge you can do the rest. How am I supposed to know which badge did you just scanned?

Comment: Basically scanning in can trigger the start time "live" using =IF(D21<>"",IF(E21<>"",E21,NOW()),"") but i cant work out how to get the "End time" live. Hence the above code is put together to try and get end times after the event, when all data has been collected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can do this with a formula in the `End Time` column that looks for the next time that Employee is listed in the `Employee ID` column.

If your table is in `F1:F100` then something like:

```
H2:  =IFERROR(INDEX(Start_Time,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(F2=F3:$F$100)*ROW(F3:$F$100),1)-1),"")
```

[image]

Algorithm:

- `F2=F3:$F$100`: look for the all matches of the ID in F2, starting at the next row
- `1/(…)`: Change the `FALSE` responses to errors
- `* ROW(…)` compute the row of the matching ID's
- `AGGREGATE` returns the smallest row number, which will be the NEXT match
- `IFERROR` to return a blank in case there is no NEXT matchg

Comment: Ron, this may well be exactly what i'm looking for, can you just explain how that works?The employee IDs will be pretty randomly distributed (i.e. every 4th task will not be done by the same person)

Comment: @HenryBorrill Explanation added to response.